# How do you refer a string to a list-array even if neither the string or list is defined?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, mapping

I will try to give a good description since it took me 5 minutes just to sum up a coherent title of my issue.

I am creating an SDK hosted on a centos7 server for a larger project, no need for details about it since it's not relevant.
What I am trying to achieve is:

- Create a list containing strings.
- Call on the list in a method as an argument.
- Instead of assigning list arrays to string (example(foo = myList[0])), be able to directly use the strings in the list only by calling on the string, without having to include the string as an argument to the said method.

I will try to give an example of what I am poorly trying to explain.

So basically, I want to somehow have the strings in myList predefined so I can directly call on the string in a method with the list as an argument.

I am fairly new to python and programming in general so my overall knowledge is pretty limited. There may be an obvious solution here but I seem to be unable to find it by googling.

The first that came to mind is just to pre-define the strings outside any method

```
(
  foo = myList[0]
  def method2(myList):
    print foo

  output> myList[0] is printed   
)
```

But that would only prompt error when loading running the script since neither the list or the strings are defined instantly, but defined through a series of other scripts.

```
def method1():

  foo = "thisisfoo"
  bar = "thisisbar"

  myList = [foo, bar]
  method2(myList)

def method2(myList):
  print foo
```

Comment: I'm not clear why you are sending in a list to a function but not using it directly, while trying to use a string that happens to be in it. Can you be more specific about what your are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Given a `method1` that sets up some variables, you can send these in to the next method:

```
def method1():

    foo = "thisisfoo"
    bar = "thisisbar"

    myList = [foo, bar]
    method2(myList, foo)

def method2(myList, foo):
    print foo
```

It's not clear what you need the list for, but send in what you need.

Changing the calling code would also work to just take the string:

```
    # as before
    method2(foo)

def method2(foo):
    print foo
```

Now, I suspect there's more context.
If you want to be able to access a variable from a few places, you could use a class.

```
class Data
    def __init__(self):
    self.foo = "thisisfoo"
    self.bar = "thisisbar"

    self.myList = [foo, bar]

    def method(self):
        print self.foo
```

Then you can make a instance and call the method:

```
    data = Data()
    data.method()
```

(`Data` is probably not the best name for a class that does stuff, but this shows how to set things up in `__init__` as members and remember them for later use).

---

Edit in light of comment.

A lightweight way to make something to hold data you want to refer to is a named tuple.

```
from collections import namedtuple
Data = namedtuple('Data','foo bar')
data = Data('one', 'two')
```

You can then access the items, `foo`, `bar` like this:

```
>>> data.foo
'one'
```

So, like the class, you state the "type" and can refer to it, before making one.

---

Or make a dictionary

```
data = {}
```

and add things as needed

```
data['Table'] = 'MyTable'
```

and use them as needed.

```
print data['Table']
```

Be aware this will raise exceptions if the item you ask for isn't there.

Comment: Hmm, not sure if this would work in my case. To give a bit more context i am currently building a deployment script for servers. The main reason why i am trying to find a solution do this is to store data in sql with sqlite3. So mainly the values i would need in "myList" would be table, column, servID. I am currently developing a custom SDK to handle sql data , create database, read and write which makes alot of submethods, in which case the strings sources will be from other scripts which calls on the "SQL-SDK" and i need to find some way to send a list of strings to a method

Comment: And still be able to call on the strings which is in the list. So is there perhaps a way to create some sort of dictionary which could refer preset strings (such as table=myList[0]) without having to store it in another method which needs to be called upon?

Comment: You could make a class. You could make a named tuple. You could use a config file. You could use argparse. Or a dictionary.

Comment: Im unsure how to do any of that to be honest, i could perhaps somehow convert the scripts i have for sql-handling to a class.. however again, not sure how to do that since ive never created a class before (the need has not ocurred so far therefor i have not learned how to do it). And this feels like it would be over my head in terms of my first class :P. So... how would a dict work? How could i create a dictionary to achieve my endeavor?

Comment: Why are you trying to use Python? It sounds like you have some kind of bulk import going on, which you could do in the db directly.

Comment: The db is a replacement from storing only in .txt/.csv files. The amount of information has grown to a point that textfiles becomes hard to maintain. Therefor the db. As mentioned the project i am working on is for replacing our old deployment system (all in python) which automated the deployment (installation+configuration) of UCS servers. The db will contain information of the servers which spans from serialnumber to cmos-battery-voltage for verification etc.

Comment: I think this has devolved into a chat. Can you break this down into separate questions about the specifics? Start a new question for each bit. Can you connect Python to the db? Can you import what you already have in text/cv files? Play with dictionaries, classes and named tuples as a learning exercise on small tasks.

Comment: Fair point. Yes i can connect python to the db by using sqlite3 module. With that interface i simply send sql queries which i insert strings to for dynamic commands. My goal is not to import from textfiles since this is a revamp from the old system. However yes, i could use old methods to load the information and then create a db with that info.

Comment: So to a solid question, how do i create a dictionary to automaticly referr to a list array (myList[x]) when calling upon a specific string in the list without having to add all strings as arguments?

Comment: I think that is a new question. I don't think you can though. How did you put them all in a list? Why not put them all in a dictionary instead?

Comment: Well that is another way to go about it i suppose, however one would still have to in each method define up the desired string such as str(table) from the dictionary in each method?

Comment: Anyhow i will try to convert the whole thing into a class, if nothing else to learn how it is done and broaden my knowledge in python. Is there a good forum to get help in this matter since it is more then a simple question, more of a need of support so to speak?

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a fitting way to do it,

Might not be the most efficient way, but it should suffice.

```
myList = [tab,col,servid]
mydict = {
    "table" : myList[0],
    "column" : myList[1]
    }


table = mydict.get("table")
column = mydict.get("column")
```

So the result from this is (table == myList[0], column == myList[1]), which should be easy enough to implement in the current scripts. 
Might be way off on this, time will tell when i advance further in the development if it works properly or not.